# DELETE unnecessary information

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that consists information about status of each customer every day. However, due to space saving, I would like to keep that information only if something has changed. More specifically:

| ID | Customer ID | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2024-02-01 | ACTIVATED |
| 2 | 1 | 2024-02-02 | ACTIVATED |
| 3 | 1 | 2024-02-03 | ACTIVATED |
| 4 | 1 | 2024-02-04 | DEACTIVATED |
| 5 | 2 | 2024-02-01 | ACTIVATED |
| 6 | 2 | 2024-02-02 | ACTIVATED |
| 7 | 3 | 2024-02-03 | ACTIVATED |
| 8 | 4 | 2024-02-04 | ACTIVATED |
| 9 | 5 | 2024-02-05 | DEACTIVATED |

How do I remove (DELETE) rows 2,3,6,7,8 and keep 1,4,5,9 with SQL?

Tried ranking, but didn't get there.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _Tried ranking, but didn't get there._ I suggest that you [edit] your question and post what you tried.

Comment: `Id=7` is the only information you have on customer 3 (and you want to DELETE it) ??

Comment: Slightly off topic: why do you store data that you don’t want?

Answer (score 0):

```
with myData as
(
    select *, 
       lag(status) over (order by id) as prevStatus 
    from myTable
)
select id, CustomerId, date, status
from myData 
where prevStatus is null or prevStatus <> status;
```

Based on this your delete would be like:

```
with myData as
(
    select *, 
       lag(status) over (order by id) as prevStatus 
    from myTable
)
delete from myTable
  where exists (select * from myData
where myTable.id = myData.Id and 
      myData.prevStatus = myData.status);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/stxhjgiv)

Answer (score 0):

When I do read your question, I think you want to keep all rows where R=1

```
SELECT *,
     row_number() OVER (partition by customer_id, status order by date asc) as R
FROM mytable
ORDER by id;
```

The DELETE statement could be:

```
DELETE 
FROM mytable
WHERE id in (
  SELECT id
  FROM (
     SELECT *,
        row_number() OVER (partition by customer_id, status order by date asc) as R
     FROM mytable
  ) x 
  where x.R>1
)
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/KeT10KBv)

Comment: It wouldn't match the result he wanted.

Comment: I commented on the question, and took the liberty of assuming I am correct .  (In your _answer_ you are comparing `LAG(status) over (order by id)` which, for example, compare the status of id=4 with the line where id=5, but that are different customers, which should not be a wanted result)

Comment: I am not assuming. Directly replied to the question. With assumption, would simply add partition by CustomerId. In either case Lag() is a better solution IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a logic behind which row to delete?
To answer the question:
*"How do I remove (DELETE) rows 2,3,6,7,8 and keep 1,4,5,9 with SQL?"*

```sql
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE ID In(2, 3, 6, 7, 8);
```

That is probably not what you were asking. We could only gues what you realy need to do. Here is one gues (though not deleting all IDs as in question) - maybe you want to delete multiple activations of customer id and keep just the first one. Below is code deleting IDs 2, 3, 6 as those customers were already activated.

```sql
--  delete multiple activations of customer id
DELETE FROM tbl 
Where ID IN ( SELECT t.ID 
              FROM ( Select ID, CUST_ID, A_DATE, STATUS, 
                            Count(A_DATE) Over(Partition By CUST_ID Order By A_DATE
                                 Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as RN
                     From tbl ) t
              WHERE RN > 1 And STATUS = 'ACTIVATED'
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [lag](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) function to bring together ordered customer, date (sample data presented already has this arrangement, but it would be *highly unlikely to occur* naturally). Then you can delete those rows that have the same `status` as the prior row for that customer. Something like: (see [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wqrir3fF))

```
delete from cust_status 
 where id in 
       (select id 
          from (select id,status
                     , lag(status) over(partition by cust_id 
                                            order by status_date) prior_status
                 from cust_status
               ) 
         where status = prior_status
      );
```

**NOTES:**  
It is poor practice using **date** as a column name. It is a Postgres *data type* and a *SQL Standard* reserved word. So demo instead uses `status_date`.  
Since your description indicates inserted *each customer each day* the demo inserts by date instead of customer id. This of course changes the id of retained and deleted rows.